# How xy different from x+y in "THE LAWS OF THOUGHT, ON WHICH ARE FOUNDED THE MATHEMATICAL THEORIES OF LOGIC AND PROBABILITIES" by Boole, George

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, self-learning, boolean-algebra

I was self studying https://archive.org/details/investigationofl00bool but could not go past the below sections. 
Chapter 2:6 if x alone stands for " white things," and y for " sheep," let xy stand for " white sheep ;"  and then 
Chapter 2:11 In this and in all other respects the words " and" " or" are analogous with the sign + in algebra, and their laws are identical. ....Let x represent " white things," y, "sheep" and let + stand for " and" and " or".

What is the difference between xy representing white sheep and x+y which may represent white and sheep? Am I missing something?

Comment: See [The Algebra of Logic Tradition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/algebra-logic-tradition/) as well as [George Boole : The Laws of Thought (1854)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boole/index.html#LawsThou1854).

Comment: Boole's original work is probably not the best introduction to propositional logic for a modern reader. He was grasping towards the first algebraic treatment of truth values and didn't have the benefit of generations of teaching experience to build on for streamlining the presentation. One of the improvements since his time is that his _notation_, overloading the algebraic notations for multiplication and addition, is somewhat rarely used nowadays. It has been found to be clearer to use specific symbols $\land$ and $\lor$ (or similar) for these meanings.

Comment: (Though the algebraic notation is still going strong in _some_ application areas -- it doesn't seem to be uncommon to meet it in digital logic, for example).

Comment: Thanks. That cleated my confusion. I was reading Treatise on probability by Keynes and Principle of Indifference notes lead me to this book.

Comment: Well, until they add $\wedge$ and $\vee$ keys to the standard keyboard, the operator overloading will continue to be used in computer science courses for the forseeable future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$xy$ means things that are white *and* sheep, i.e. white sheep

$x+y$ means things that are either white *or* sheep. This includes white sheep, but also such things as white saladshooters, and black sheep.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what that statement meant ....+ stand for "and" or "or" ? Why are we using "or" why not "and"

Comment: @user566158 I was just reading the relevant passage ... Boole does indeed something a bit strange here; it seems like he is using the $+$ to represent either the 'or" or the 'and'.  For example, he seems to use x + y = y + x to indicate that both 'x and y = y and x', as well as 'x or y = y or x'. So that is indeed rather confusing. However, in modern notation the $+$ is definitely interpreted as just the 'or' ... Indeed, you may be better off reading some more modern texts on formal logic, which are not only more up to date, but also more readable than Boole's book.

Comment: Thanks. That cleared my confusion.

Comment: @sreenadha Boole didn't mean $+$ was sometimes "or" and othertimes "and", he was indicating that $+$ meant *inclusive-or* so: $x$ and/or $y$ to emphasise that *at least one but maybe both* are true.

Comment: @Graham Kemp, In Boole's word, chapter 2 page 33, Let x represent " men," y, "women ;" and let + stand for " and" and " or" then we have x+y=y+z.......Let the symbol z stand for the adjective " European," then since it is, in effect, the same thing to say " European men and women," as to say " European men and European women," we have z(x+y) = zx + zy.   I tend to agree more with Henning Makholm and Bram28 than inclusive-or argument which though seems plausible creates lot more confusion with his text.

Comment: @sreenadha Agreed. In the passage 2.11 Boole is saying that when we say "men and women", we use the word "and" to indicate that the two classes are distinct.  But sometimes we use the word "or" for this as well. Boole then uses + to capture either of those uses .. (which kind of makes sense: the class people would be the 'aggregate' of men and women).  But the confusing thing is that with other uses of the word "and" we mean that something is both. That's why $xy$ would be white sheep (things that are white and a sheep).

Comment: @sreenadha To add to the confusion, Boole's use of the +, which as pointed out seems compatible with an exclusive or, is incompatible with the modern use of + in logic as an inclusive or. I am also wondering what Boole would actually say about $x+y$ if $x$ is white and $y$ is sheep .. because we're not talking about separate classes here that we aggregrate into a larger one using the +. (and maybe it is exactly that difficulty that made us change the use of + from exclusive or to inclusive or ...)

Comment: @sreenadha You know, I *really* want to reiterate my point to read a more modern treatment of logic! Boole's notation is not only confusing, but as I am reading passage, but not all that nice to work with either (he uses a - for 'exclusion' ...1-x instead of x', etc.)

Answer (score 0):

$xy$ here is something that's both white and shep, while $x+y$ is something that is white, or is a sheep (or both).

Comment: Why can't we use "and" for +?  ....+ stand for "and" or "or" ? Why are we using "or" why not "and"

Comment: @sreenadha Boole never used $+$ for just "and" alone.  He was trying to emphasise that it meant "and/or"; that is *inclusive-or*.